# changing password with ansible on older systems

Tags: ansible

I need to change the password on a user for over a hundred system. I want to do this with ansible. Which is easy. However the user module on ansible requires a hashed password. I am concerned because there are a few older hosts which may not support newer types of hashing. I want to be able to programmatically identify what password hashing algorithms are available, and use the appropriate password hash to change. Or is there perhaps a better way to handle this whole sale.

I have considered the following:

```
echo username:password | chpasswd
```

and run that using the command module. That should use whatever the default algorithm is. Is there any cause for concern with this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind, the ideal way would be to figure the supported hashes for each machine and then generate the [proper hash](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) for each machine.

The approach you list should work Just make sure you at "no_log: yes" to your task to ensure the password doesn't end up in the log file.

With either approach you're going to need have a way of getting the password(s) into ansible to use with the user module.  Not sure if the passwords will be in a CSV file, yaml file or some other format.   You could consider using  [vault to lock](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) things down a bit more.

Comment: I plan to use vault to supply the password to the playbook. Thanks for the no_log suggestion. Maybe I can add a staging user to all systems, add it to all the admin groups. Then run a playbook with that user, su to root, then change root password; finally remove the staging user. Im just worried about locking myself out on all machines.